# Groovy extend TimeCategory class

Tags: groovy

Hello I got a question about using TimeCategory in groovy.
in My project, I got unique method for calculating months. I want to add it to TimeCategory.

```
public Integer calcMonateAboDays(def fromDate) {
Date startDate
if (fromDate instanceof String) {
    startDate = fromDate.toDate()
} else if (fromDate instanceof Date) {
    startDate = fromDate
} else {
    assert false: "Wrong fromDate class: " + fromDate.getClass()
}
Date endDate = null
use(TimeCategory) {
    endDate = startDate + 1.month

    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    endCalendar.setTime(endDate)
    int lastDayOfMonth = endCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    int endDayOfMonth = endCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    startCalendar.setTime(startDate)
    int startDayOfMonth = startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    if (lastDayOfMonth != endDayOfMonth || startDayOfMonth == lastDayOfMonth) {
        endDate--
    }
}
return (endDate - startDate) + 1
}
```

How can I add it to existing TimeCategory class to use like this:

```
Date date = new Date()
use(TimeCategory) {
    System.out.print(date + 1.monateAbo)
}
```

Stuff like this:

```
TimeCategory.metaClass.getMonateAbo() {
```

}

doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

1. Extension methods must be defined as static. The first argument to the method declares the type and instance gaining the defined method. Subsequent arguments are the actual arguments to that method. This is explained more in depth in the [Groovy metaprogramming documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_instance_methods).
2. You don't necessarily need to add the extension method to `TimeCategory` in order to be able to use it as an extension method. [The `use` method](http://www.groovy-lang.org/design-patterns.html#_pimp_my_library_pattern) works with any class.

For example:

```
class MonateAboCategory {
    static int getMonateAbo(Integer instance) {
        // do calculations
    }
    static int getMonateAbo(Date instance) {
       // do calculations
    }
}

use(MonateAboCategory) {
    println new Date() - 1.monateAbo    
    println new Date().monateAbo
}
```

Now, if you want to be able to use both the extension methods defined in `TimeCategory` *and* in your custom extension class, you can either nest `use` methods:

```
use(MonateAboCategory) {
    use (groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
        println new Date() + 3.months
        println new Date() - 1.monateAbo    
    }
}
```

Or you can define the custom extension class as a subclass of `TimeCategory`:

```
class MonateAboCategory extends groovy.time.TimeCategory {
    static int getMonateAbo(Integer val) ...
}

use(MonateAboCategory) {
    println new Date() + 3.months
    println new Date() - 1.monateAbo    
}
```